# Cubic interpolation derivation

Tags: interpolation

I have seen the following cubic interpolation formula in multiple books on multigrid:

$$f(x) = -\frac{1}{16}f(x-3h) + \frac{9}{16}f(x-h) + \frac{9}{16}f(x+h) -\frac{1}{16}f(x+3h).$$

Applying the above to some vector $v_i = f(x + (1+2i)h)$, such that $v_i = \delta^k_i$ yields: $(-\frac{1}{16}, 0, \frac{9}{16}, 1, \frac{9}{16}, 0, -\frac{1}{16})$. I do not understand how the initial expression for $f(x)$ was derived however. The best I could find was a paper on pseudo-splines [Multigrid methods: grid transfer operators and subdivision schemes](http://Multigrid%20methods:%20grid%20transfer%20operators%20and%20subdivision%20schemes) where they call the above "the classical cubic interpolation $p_{2,1}$" though I must say the pseudo-splines explanation goes way over my head.

At the very least I could not derive it in the same way I derived the weights for linear interpolation:

$$\frac{f(x_0+t) - f(x_0)}{f(x_1)-f(x_0)} = \frac{x_0+t-x_0}{x_1-x_0} \implies f(x_0+t) = f(x_0) + \frac{t}{x_1-x_0}(f(x_1)-f(x_0))$$
$$\text{let}\, x_1-x_0 = 1 \implies f(x_0+t) = (1-t)f(x_0) + tf(x_1)\implies \\ f\left(x_0+\frac{1}{2}\right) = \frac{1}{2}f(x_0) + \frac{1}{2}f(x_1)$$

For the cubic case I understand that the function $f$ is constructed to interpolate the points $(x\pm h, \frac{9}{16}f(x\pm h)),\, (x\pm 3h, -\frac{1}{16}f(x\pm 3h))$, but I do not understand what the idea was behind making it interpolate those. If someone told me that $f$ should be a cubic interpolating function, then I would have made it interpolate $(x\pm 3h, f(x\pm 3h))$ and $(x\pm h, f(x\pm h))$ similar to the linear case, but this is clearly not the function that is given above.

Comment: Those coefficients are  the values at 0 of cubic Lagrange polynomials  for points -3,-1,1 and 3.

Comment: @blamocur You mean $l_j(x) = \prod_{k\ne j}\frac{x-x_k}{x_j-x_k}$? Are the $x_k \in \{\pm 1, \pm 3\}$?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.The value will be the same when you switch to an arbitrary $x$ and $x_0=x-3h, x_1=x-h, x_2=x+h, x_3=x+3h$.

Comment: @blamocur Thank you, this clarifies everything. Feel free to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those coefficients are the values at 0 of cubic Lagrange polynomials for points -3,-1,1 and 3.Those values will be the same for arbitrary $x$ and $x_k = x + (2k-3)h$